# AVCaptureSession preset creates a photo that is too big

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have a photo taking app that is using `AVFoundation`. Once an image is captured, I have 2 core graphics methods that I have to run in order to properly rotate and crop the image.

When testing this using the [typical AVFoundation setup for capturing camera photos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22700723/3344977) with a session preset of `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`, I was always receiving a ton of memory warnings and I spent 2 weeks trying to solve these and I finally gave up.

I ended up ditching the typical `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` setup and using another setup that just "captures" the video frames. This new method works perfectly, the final image quality matches the old image quality produced by `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` and the image has a much smaller resolution so I am no longer dealing with memory issues or warnings.

The image rotation and crop also happens almost instantly now and is almost completely unnoticeable since the new size is much smaller.

Literally the only difference, as far as I can tell, is that `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` produces a photo with a resolution of `2448 x 3264` whereas my new method produces a resolution of `852 x 640` yet the quality appears to be identical.

However, since this new method does not technically perform a real "camera capture", I am going to have to spend some time adding the camera sound effect, programmatically calling the flash/torch to add flash functionality, etc. Before I start down this road of customization I decided to revisit my old setup that developers typically use when capturing photos using `AVFoundation`.

Here's a link to the "typical" setup that I'm talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22700723/3344977

I tested all of the session presets one last time and none of them work like `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`. The resolution is either too small, or the resolution could possibly work but the preview is zoomed in which is unacceptable.

Are there any other options? Can I some how disable the zoom on some of these presets? Or can I customize the actual image size for the `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` preset? Can I create a new custom preset from scratch and add that?

I have been searching for answers but it seems like most people just recommend using the default presets that are available.

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfying answer? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @mathz I asked this a long time ago but if I remember correctly there is a way to specify a custom resolution, but that may just be for video capture.

Comment: So no answer to this?